# Offering discounts to specific customers via coupons in IOS App Store

Tags: ios, store

I know that you can offer a free version of your application by generating a promo code in iTunes connect. I am also aware that you can temporarily change the price of your application in iTunes connect (Rights and Pricing).  However, is there any way to create a coupon code that would give a non-free but discounted price to a specific customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible with the App Store. There you can only set one price for all or give the app away using a promo code. Note that Apple explicitly forbids selling those promo codes.